Find minimum number of nodes to be removed so that each node has atmost one adjacent node in a graph (not necessarily a DAG)
I have directed graph G (not necessarily a DAG).
I need to formulate an algorithm returning the minimum number of nodes that need to be removed, such that each node has atmost one adjacent node.
Any idea on which algorithm to use or how to proceed further?
I'm completely stuck on this.

Define 'adjacent'. In the directed graph $A \to B \to C$ is $B$ adjacent to 1 or 2 nodes? If only $1$, do only incoming or outgoing edges count? In the graph $B \to B$, is $B$ adjacent to itself?
